# How to animate Button's Content property with Image control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Button control. I fill its Content property with Image control referencing some .png file in the project's sources.

Then I want the button to switch its Content property to another image once I press it or hold mouse over it.

What am I done: I have created a style to overwrite default button's template and added own triggers: one for IsPressed and one for IsMouseOver properties.

To react on IsPressed property I need to make Storyboard (I'm not sure why but just to add Setter doesn't work) so I added Storybard where changed Button's Content property with needed Image.

But once I have run the app I got an exception like 
"Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads."

I suppose it's because of Image control couldn't be freezed or something like.

So the question is: how to achieve my very simple goal with some simple actions (or any other way). I think it's very strange to make so simple things so long and hard way.

Sorry my poor english and thanks in advance.

Below the XAML code of my button's style

```
<Style x:Key="AcceptWordButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        >
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="PART_Content"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            >

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Source="WizardButton.png"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Button.Content">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Image Source="WizardButtonPressed.png"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="WizardButtonHovered.png"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: If you want to "*switch its Content property to another image*" then assign another Image element to the Content property, instead of setting the existing Image's Source property.

Comment: @Clemens, sorry there should be Storyboard.TargetProperty="Button.Content" of course, fixed;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning the Source property of an Image element that was set by a Style Setter, just put an Image in the Button's `ContentTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="AcceptWordButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="WizardButton.png"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="WizardButtonHovered.png"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="WizardButtonPressed.png"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Not exactly the same 'cause it kills default button's "chrome" but it's enough for me for now, thx

Comment: Then just remove the ControlTemplate. See the edited answer.